# backtraking DUCU in java java

Tags: java, backtracking, recursive-backtracking

this code results an StackOverFlowError, but I can't pin point where the problem is.

```
public boolean backtracking(int n, ArrayList<Point2D.Double> R, ArrayList<Point2D.Double> S) {
    ArrayList<Point2D.Double> C = new ArrayList<>();
    if (R.isEmpty()) return true;
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i <= R.size() - 1; i++) {

            Point2D.Double currentPt = R.remove(i);
            S.add(currentPt);
            Ellipse2D.Double circle = new Ellipse2D.Double(currentPt.x - r, currentPt.y - r, r * 2, r * 2);

            for (int j = 0; j <= R.size()-1 ; j++){
                if (circle.contains(R.get(j))){
                    C.add(R.remove(j));
                }
            }

            backtracking(n+1, R, S);

            if (!C.isEmpty())   R.addAll(C);
            R.add(S.remove(S.size() - 1));
        }

    }
    return false;
}
```

Ps. this "should" be a method that calculates the minimum number of circles that is needed to cover all the points in the R array list.

Comment: FYI, `i < R.size()` is equivalent to, and more conventional than `i <= R.size() - 1`.

Comment: no doesn't solve the problem, but thanx!

Comment: I didn't say it would solve a problem. In fact, I said it's equivalent to what you have.